# What is the proper ld link script syntax for aliasing missnamed symbols with the PROVIDE statement?

Tags: c, linker, ld, linker-scripts, missing-symbols

I'm trying to understand how I can provide aliases to missnamed
symbols when linking libraries with gnu `ld`. If I understand
correctly it should be sufficient to define an addition to the default
link script as

```
PROVIDE(undefined_symbol = existing_symbol);
```

however my minimal non-working example below does not seem to recognize
the symbol `foo` which should be defined in `foo.o`. Any ideas or hints what the correct link script syntax is would be
very appreciated?

foo.c:

```c
int foo(int a) {
  return a + 1;
}
```

foo.h:

```c
int foo(int a);
```

main.c:

```c
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int b = foo_(1);   // calling foo_ instead of foo
  printf("%d\n", b);
  return 0;
}
```

script.ld:

```
PROVIDE(foo_ = foo);
```

compile and link:

```bash
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar rcs foo.a foo.o
gcc -I. -c -o main.o main.c
gcc main.o foo.a -o test script.ld

> /usr/bin/ld:script.ld:1: undefined symbol 'foo' referenced in expression


> nm foo.a
foo.o:
0000000000000000 T foo

> nm main.o
                 U foo_
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 T main
                 U printf
```